# I can't show the dates in the same embed with python from discord BOT

Tags: python

I have created a bot for discord that shows all the dates of any fortnite skin through the api, but my problem is that it does not show me all the dates inside the embed with the !skin command, it only shows me a date in timestamp format

this is the code:

```
@bot.command()
async def skin(ctx):
    url = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")
    historialSKIN= url.json()
    
    for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
     for datestr in i['shopHistory']:
        fecha = int(isoparse(datestr).timestamp())

    embed=discord.Embed(title="Titulo", description=f"{fecha}")
    embed.add_field(name="Skin", value="skin", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

What should I do to show all the dates in the same embed?

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

I should stay like this:

[image]

can someone help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Mayve don't cast the date to `int` here? `fecha = int(isoparse(datestr).timestamp())`

Comment: It only shows me a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable "fecha" must be array or string to contain all your dates.

Here's the code, it should work. I think I've shown you the problem and then you'll figure it out for yourself.

```
@bot.command()
async def skin(ctx):
    url = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")
    historialSKIN= url.json()
    fecha = ""
    for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
     for datestr in i['shopHistory']:
        fecha += str(isoparse(datestr).timestamp()) +"\n"

    embed=discord.Embed(title="Titulo", description=fecha)
    embed.add_field(name="Skin", value="skin", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```